# Re-assign value to the function parameter break the control flow based type analysis

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I re-assign the function parameter, it will break the [Control flow based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis). I known re-assign the param is a code smell and violate the eslint rule [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). But it's ok for JavaScript. Just wonder why TSC can't narrow the type anymore?
How to solve this without type assertion?

Code:

```
function bar(arg: string | (() => string)): void {
 
}

function foo(arg: string | string[]) {
  arg = 'aa'
  if(typeof arg === 'string') {
    console.log('arg is string type: ', arg)
    bar(arg)

    // why the type.of arg here is string | string[]?
    bar(() => arg)
  } else {
    console.log('arg is string[] type: ', arg)
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYCcAUGDmAuRAZynRjB0QB9FNMBKRAXgD4iSyc66CA3OGACaIA3gChEogL6jRoSLASJgcONnT42pclU0cA2gF0GYxIlxNEAclSpL4xDGCYoATwAOAUzjAz6po0YrYi0cS2N7UwgEQjgAGw8AOli4HExrPxhCXW1XTwJLABpfTgiUDDUS0oB6KsQAdwALF0QoBo8W90TvYsQ29HbM7IpqYP0DAH5StCx6JlZcOntJRA9YwnaTU0QosBj4pJS080HR8kMOvKsihaWpGSA)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're opening yourself up to modifying arg before it's used by passing it as a function.

This breaks the guarantee of arg returning a string - see below:

```js
function bar(arg: string | (() => string)): void {
 setTimeout(() => {
   if (typeof arg === 'function') {
      const result = arg();
      console.log('arg is: ', result);

      if (Array.isArray(result)) {
        // Wait, I thought arg was meant to be a string?
        console.log('I crashed!');
      }
   }
 }, 300);
}

function foo(arg: string | string[]) {
  arg = 'aa'
  if(typeof arg === 'string') {
    console.log('arg is string type: ', arg)

    bar(arg)

    // why the type.of arg here is string | string[]?
    bar(() => arg as string);

    // Now change arg before setTimeout expires
    arg = ['a', 'b'];
  } else {
    console.log('arg is string[] type: ', arg)
  }
}

foo('a');
// -> 'arg is: ['a', 'b']'
// -> 'I crashed!'
```

Comment: Type assertion is fine. Still, I am looking for the reason.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm only adding the type assertion because it, rightly, won't compile. My example shows an example of how, if TS allowed it to compile, it would break soundness of the type system and lead to errors.